# Probability of majority when voting with 3 parties

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

**How would you determine the probability that there strict majority of voters in a 3 party system?** **In particular, when there are 3, 4 and 5 voters.**

In other words, if you have a randomized 3 people, who can have the same voting preferences, what is the probability there will be a majority?

*Here is what I have tried so far:*

**1) Binomial Theorem 

2) Combinatorics**

So for 3 parties there are **3! = 6** different arrangements of voting preferences:

- A>B>C
- A>C>B
- B>A>C
- B>C>A
- C>A>B
- C>B>A

From this, I know that there a total of  **$6^3$** = $\binom{6} {1} $ $\binom{6} {1} $$\binom{6} {1} $  different possibilities with repetition.

### Binomial Probability

The probability of any person having a given first choice is 1/3 
Let p= prob of success = 1/3 
Let q= 1-p= 2/3          i.e probability of not having the same vote

A majority of 3 is either 3/3 people or 2/3 people:

*If 2 people of 3 have same 1st choice:*

P (X=2) = $\binom{3} {2} $ $(1/3)^2$ $(2/3)^1$ = 6/27

*If 3 people of 3 have same 1st choice:*

P (X=3) = $\binom{3} {3} $ $(1/3)^3$ = 1/27

The sum of these  = 7/27 = about 25.926 %

Therefore the probability of there being a majority with 3 voters is **7/27** = 
**25.93 %**

FOR 5 PEOPLE: 
I can extend this to 5 people where there is still p=1/3 and q=2/3, and a majority is obtained by 5 out 5 voters, 4 out of 5 or 3 out of 5. 

Thus the probability for a majority is 
P(X>2) = P (X=3) + P(X=4) + P(X=5)
= $\binom{5} {3} $ $(1/3)^3$ $(2/3)^2$ +$\binom{5} {4} $ $(1/3)^4$ $(2/3)^1$ +$\binom{5} {5} $ $(1/3)^5$ 
= 51/243

### Combinatorics

If I want there to ***not*** be a majority with 3 people, then I need to pick, say, 1 person with A as a 1st choice, the next person with a B as their first choice, and the last person with C as their first choice  
 
So, any of the 6 preferences for the 1st person, any of the 4 remaining preferences that exclude A as their first choice, and then any of the 2 remaining preferences for the 3rd voter :

$\binom{6} {1} $ $\binom{4} {1} $ $\binom{2} {1} $ = 6*4*2 = 48

Thus the probability of there ***NOT*** being a majority is **48/216** which is about 0.2222.

Then the probability of there being a majority is **77.78%**, which is contradicts with the binomial theorem results.

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks a ton!!

**EDIT:** I just realized that if I multiply my binomial result by 3, the number of voters, I get the same result as by combinatorics.  
(Since there are 3 different initial voter choices i.e the 1st voter can pick A, and then I find the probability of at least one the other 2 picking A, then it's the same probability the first voter votes for B or C, similar to arranging people around a table).

How can I extend this result to 4 and 5 people though?

Comment: You need to use multinomial distribution to model the number of votes obtained for each party (assuming each voter is independent and equally likely to vote for each party). When the number of voters $n = 3$ is a multiple of $3$, we have a possible 3-way tie for the maximum. The probability of having a tied maximum, for $n = 3$ is given by $\displaystyle \frac {3!} {1!1!1!} \frac {1} {3^3} = \frac {2} {9}$ (i.e. the $(1, 1, 1)$ case). For $n = 4$, the only possible tied maximum is $(2, 2, 0)$ (and you need to multiply by $\binom {3} {2}$ for the generic case). For $n = 5$ is $(2, 2, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your response @BGM! 
Yeah, each voter is equally likely to vote for each party and voters are independent.

So for n=4,
$$P (A=2, B=2, C=1) = 4!/ (2! 2! 0!) * (1/3)^2 *(1/3)^2 *(1/3)^0 $$ $$= 6/(3)^4$$ $$= 0.074074$$


n=5

$$P (A=2, B=2, C=1) = 5!/ (2! 2! 1!) * (1/3)^2 *(1/3)^2 *(1/3)^2 $$
                              $$= 30/(3)^5$$
                               $$= 0.12345679$$

But what number do we multiply for the permutations of these (say A=1, B=2, C=1) ? Could you please explain where your $(3 chose 2) $ comes from?

And does my n=3 case hold?